# i am getting a low severity vulnerability related to lodash while installing passport google oauth

Tags: passport.js, google-oauth

what is this vulnerability issue that i am getting. can someone explain.
i got this while i installed passport-google-oauth20.

[lenovo@lenovo-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/WebDev/Authentication and Security/Secrets
$ npm i mongoose-findorcreate
npm WARN Secrets@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN Secrets@1.0.0 No repository field.

- mongoose-findorcreate@3.0.0
  added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 179 packages in 12.114s

2 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

lenovo@lenovo-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/WebDev/Authentication and Security/Secrets
$ npm audit

```
                   === npm audit security report ===                        
                                                                            
                                                                            
                             Manual Review                                  
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             
                                                                            
      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
```

Low             Prototype Pollution

Package         lodash

Patched in      No patch available

Dependency of   mongoose-encryption

Path            mongoose-encryption > async > lodash

More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1523

found 1 low severity vulnerability in 179 scanned packages
1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N3ZY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It means that the package has a known vulnerability in this case one with low severity. To clarify it is not related to installing passport, but rather the version of lodash you are using in the project.

To resolve the issue you can just run `npm audit fix` and it will update the module.